# Metric, Curvature, Connection

Tags: soft-question, riemannian-geometry

I am new of riemannian geometry and I am not sure of implications of metrics. Metrics implies riemann connection with no torsion and metric compatibility.
Connection implies curvature of the connection or does it only depens on the metric?

Comment: I think you mean a smooth manifold can give the meaning of a connection. A metric is something that is added to a manifold structure. Unless you are referring to a Riemannian Manifold, because that's what I am assuming from you saying "riemann connection". The curvature tensor is defined in terms of only the connection.

Answer (score 0):

Curvature depends on connection. In imprecise words, curvature is the composition of connection and derivation. In general connection is an object associated to vector bundle over a smooth manifold and so is the curvature and hence it has nothing to do with a metric. In case of Riemannian manifold, we have a special connection, namely the Rimennian connection whose existence and uniqueness depends on the Riemannin metric and hence the curvature associated to it also depends on the metric. For more details see Chapter 12 of [this](http://www.seas.upenn.edu/~jean/diffgeom.pdf) lecture note.

Comment: Thank you. I would upvote your answer but the system doesn't aloud me since I'm suppose to be more than 15 point and I'm only 6... but thank you for you kind explanation

Comment: @Arch That's okay. I am glad that it helped you.